# Can't import a local sub directory

Tags: go

I have the main file "main.go" in the root of my project and there's also a subdirectory named "models" wherein there're multiple *.go files as well.
In the main.go there's this:

```
import "./models"
```

When I build the project

```
go build
```

this error appears:

```
main.go:16:2: package models is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/models)
```

How to fix this?

Also, what if I created subdirectories inside "models" as well, how and from where would I have to import them? Later on I'll need this.

Comment: You import packages in go, not folders. Have a look [here](https://golang.org/doc/code) for some examples.

Comment: @super I've seen those examples.

Comment: @super besides, in my case there's only one package - "main", and it holds  for the files in the sub directories as well

Comment: If you've already seen those examples, why are you not following them? Go imposes a strict folder structure on your project. Each packages must be in it's own folder. You can't split a package across multiple folders. You import by using the package name.

Comment: “How to Write Go Code” does cover importing another package. You can also read through https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

In you project, lets call it testmodule. You should have a subdirectory called models. In that subdirectory you use the packagename models.

When you import the subpackage in your main package you refer to it as testmodule/models. So you mainpackage/the subpackage you want to import